# Passing mutable data between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Here's a basic question about multi-threading in Java: I have a very big mutable data structure (a tree, to be exact) and I understand that if I want to modify this data structure concurrently from two different threads, I need to use locks and/or other kinds of thread safety.

However, in my case, the two threads don't need to modify the data structure *at the same time*; rather, thread A, which normally owns the data structure, should temporarily pass the latter to thread B, and thread B should pass the data structure back to thread A after having done some long-running modifications on it.

Is it thread-safe to pass this mutable data structure back and forth between threads, if it's guaranteed that the threads do not modify the data at the same time?

Comment: How is it guaranteed that `the threads do not modify the data at the same time?`

Comment: Regarding the visibility issues that everybody is mentioning--Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz is a great resource for learning more about this.

Comment: @Eypros: Thread A passes the data to thread B, and thread B passes it back to thread A, so A knows when the data is modified by B, and therefore, when it's not allowed to touch the data.

Comment: @ankit337 The backticks are for inline-code only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the threads don't modify the tree at the same time (i.e. by atomically passing over the only reference to the tree), it is fine from a thread-safety point of view.

Data visibility / consistency is another concern, though. Unless all fields in the tree are (recursively) declared `volatile`, changes made by one thread may not become visible to the other thread. To avoid, make sure a monitor (which acts as a memory barrier and ensures that all writes becomes visible) is acquired when the threads exchange ownership of the tree.

Comment: For clarification, are you saying that the monitor only needs to be held during the data exchange, and not throughout the modification done by the second thread?

Comment: Other answers are more accurate here: you simply need to establish the `happens-before` relationship between A 'owning' the tree and B 'owning the tree' - how you do it does not matter. However, to acquire a monitor when changing ownership (i.e. enter a `synchronized` block) is a straightforward way to do it. You don't need to hold if afterwards, it only serves to establish a memory barrier at the point of exchange.

Comment: @pythondude - No, he is telling the monitor must be acquired by the second thread once it starts working on the data structure *and keep it until it finishes*.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, what you are describing would work just fine **as long as you take specific steps to avoid memory consistency errors** when you're passing the object between threads. Using locking is one way to achieve this, but there are other -- less expensive -- ways.

The [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) is a good starting point.

Basically, you need to ensure that when thread A is passing the object to thread B, all changes by A *happen-before* B accesses the object.

There's more in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5), but it's rather technical.

Answer (score 5):

This is *not* thread-safe without a further synchronization guarantee.

Basically, one cannot be sure of *consistent visibility* between threads without proper synchronization - such as `synchronized`, or other happens-before guarantees of the JLS. That is, even though there may be no "concurrent modifications", there is *no* guarantee that the non-writer thread sees the modifications to said object.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but this still begs the question of how you will transfer ownership of the data between threads. The answer is that this is typically done with locks; holding the lock represents that the given thread is currently the one in charge that is allowed to mutate the object.

It's also imporant to note that thread safety is a concern whenever there are one or more readers and at least one writer. Just because both objects are not modifying the object at the same time, it will still be an issue if one thread is reading from the structure at the same time that it is being mutated.

So, to get to the point: keep it simple and just use a lock.

Answer (score 3):

In general it isn't, but in many specific case it could turn out to work (just don't rely on those).

Locking does two things.

1. It prevents two threads from accessing the same data at the same time.
2. When a lock is taken all the caches that the program/system has are flushed. This is also why the keyword in java is called `synchronized`.

If in some way you can make a mechanism that does it's own locking (that is really what you are saying) you still need to make sure that all the data is synchronized across threads. Locking isn't the only way to do this, but its is an added feature of it.

Comment: The keyword is “synchronize **d**” not “synchronize”

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have create custom data structure.

Try to create your dataStructure class `Synchronized` [like this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncrgb.html)
Use carefully with `synchronized` block where needed as shown in example.

If you need to share same data over all thread then create `static Synchronized` methods and `private static` variables, So even though by mistake you create multiple instance of dataStructure class it is thread safe

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by a simple volatile helper variable:

```
class OwnedTree{
    private volatile Thread owner;
    private Tree tree;

    //once a thread calls this with a the!=Thread.currentThread() then it may not use Tree returned from getTree any more
    public void passToThread(Thread thr){
        if(Thread.currentThread().equals(owner))
            owner = thr;//volatile write ensures happens-before
    }

    public Tree getTree(){
        if(!Thread.currentThread().equals(owner))//volatile read ensures happens-before
            throw new IllegalStateException();//or return null;
        return tree;
    }

    public Thread getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }

}
```

the semantics of volatile reads and writes ensure all changes will be visible if this class is used correctly

Comment: Here's a good explanation of why this works: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html